# Scripting - vertex won't extrude

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to make a simple script that extrude vertex in random ways,
all works without extrude.

I do not know if it's good I wrote, but I do not know how to extrude vertex to the location of the cursor.
Any idea what is wrong with my code and how to fix it?
I run script in Edit mode with one vertex on the scene.

```
import bpy
import random

#generate random number
def RN():
    return int(random.random()*400)/20

for i in range(1,100):
#set 3d cursor to random location
    bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = (RN(),RN(),RN())
#extrude vertex to cursor location - doesn't work
    bpy.ops.mesh.dupli_extrude_cursor(rotate_source=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking the `bpy.ops.mesh.dupli_extrude_cursor(rotate_source=True)`
 operator leads to this error message in the console window:

```
wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call 'MESH_OT_dupli_extrude_cursor'
```

Although is is exactly what is printed in info header when manually extruding a vertex.

I can't tell why this doesn't work but try this:

```
import bpy
import random

#generate random number
def RN():
    return int(random.random()*400)/20

verts = []
edges = []
faces = []
for i in range(1,100):
#set 3d cursor to random location
    verts.append(( RN(),RN(),RN()))
    edges.append((i-1,i))
edges.pop() # remove last edge
print( verts )
print ( edges )
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("rand_mesh") 
mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)  
rand_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("rand_object", mesh) 
scene = bpy.context.scene 
scene.objects.link(rand_obj)
```

I really don't know for what something like this could be useful:

[image]

See also

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Geometry

Answer (score 1):

It has no `execute()` method, but the default operator context is `EXEC_DEFAULT`. You need to use `INVOKE_DEFAULT` to make it call `invoke()`.

However, it doesn't work as expected: `cursor` stands for the user mouse, not the 3D Cursor, and it will thus only extrude correctly if you make the following code an operator and run it in *3D View* context:

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        ctx = bpy.context.copy()
        ctx['area'] = area
        ctx['region'] = area.regions[-1]
        ctx['space_data'] = area.spaces.active
        bpy.ops.mesh.dupli_extrude_cursor(ctx, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT', rotate_source=True)
        break
```

If you run it from the *PyConsole* or *Text Editor* instead, it will extrude to a point outside the viewport (towards where the mouse is on screen).